# Maintain the position of the prefix in TextFormField when changing to a locale that has different direction ( LTR | RTL )

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextFormField` that takes a phone number. I need to maintain the direction of the prefix when I change the language of the app (which changes the direction).

You see in this screenshot that I managed to maintain the text input direction using `textDirection: TextDirection.ltr` but the prefix direction still adapts to the RTL layout. Is there a way to keep the prefix in the left position?

```dart
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Phone Number',
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            locale: Locale('en','')
        ),
        prefixText: ' +968 ',
        prefixStyle: const TextStyle(
          locale: Locale('en',''),
        ),
        helperText: ''),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, a prefix will always be at the beginning of the textfield, so let it be. What we can do here is use a conditional InputDecoration and switch between prefixText and suffixText. This way we don't have to go against the framework and our job will also be done.
Suppose we have two languages, English(EN) and Urdu(UR). so our code will be:

```
    String lang = "UR";
    
      TextDirection getTextDirection() {
        return lang == "EN" ? TextDirection.ltr : TextDirection.rtl;
      }
    
      InputDecoration getInputDecoration() {
        if (lang == 'EN')
          return InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Phone Number',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(locale: Locale('en', '')),
              prefixText: ' +968 ',
              prefixStyle: const TextStyle(
                locale: Locale('en', ''),
              ),
              helperText: '');
        else
          return InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Phone Number',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(locale: Locale('en', '')),
              suffixText: ' +968 ',
              suffixStyle: const TextStyle(
                locale: Locale('en', ''),
              ),
              helperText: '');
      }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
body:
       TextFormField(
         keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
         textDirection:getTextDirection(),
         decoration:getInputDecoration(),
       )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the TextFormField with **Directionality**

```
Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          maxLines: widget.maxLines ?? 1,
          readOnly: widget.readOnly ?? false,
          keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
          maxLength: widget.maxLength ?? (widget.isPhone ? 8 : null),
          inputFormatters: widget.textInputFormatter,
          style: widget.textStyle,.....
```

Comment: Perfect answer, its works truly for me